# Insert error bars into a barplot from table

Tags: bar-chart, errorbar

I have transformed values from a table into a barplot. In the same table there are also the error values (in another column). Is it possible to insert these error values directly from the table into the barplot.

My code so far:

```
setwd("D:/data")
table<- read.table("values.txt", dec = ".", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
x=show(table)
ggplot(table, aes(x=values, y=AoI)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "gray", color="black") +
  labs(x = "values", y = "AoI") +
  theme_gray() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = error_1, ymax = error_2), width=0.9) +
  theme_classic()
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I then get a very consumed image.

Best regards

Comment: What language and libraries are you using?

Comment: R, library(ggplot2)